# How to write ffmpeg command "-ss" in Python

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I have this command in ffmpeg that I want to write in Python,

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:12:14 -i video.mp4 -vframes 1 output.png
```

Is it possible to write this in Python?

Comment: Please clarify your question. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

Kinda depends on what you mean by 'write this in Python'.

Using the subprocess module:

```
import subprocess

cmd = ['ffmpeg', '-ss', '00:12:14', '-i', 'video.mp4', '-vframes', '1', 'output.png']

cmdproc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    line = cmdproc.stdout.readline()
    if not line:
        break
```

(or something similar, since there's check_output(), call()...)

If you mean by a 'native' way of doing that, you can try out ffmpeg-python [1],
though I know nothing about that.

[1] - https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python

Answer (score 1):

using the [python bindings](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python), you'd write it like this:

```py
ffmpeg.input('video.mp4', vframes=1, ss=('00:12:14')).output('output.png').run()
```

(not 100% sure if the ss filter takes the time params like this, if that doesn't work use count of seconds instead)

Comment: great answer, exactly what I needed. I got an error saying that I mixed up the input and output files for `vframes`. I got it running with `ffmpeg.input('video.mp4', ss=('00:12:14')).output('output.png', vframes=1).run()`